# strange behaviour.. please suggest some solution

Tags: c++

I have encountered one very strange problem. I am trying to explain full scenario here. Please suggest some solution.

```
/* "test.h" */
class A : public B
{
    public:
       A();
       bool isUp;
};

/* test.cpp */
#include "test.h"
A::A()
{
    isUp = false;             //`isUp' was not declared in this scope
}
```

What is it means if I am declaring it in `.h` inside `class`. If I am wrong then what approach I need to follow.

EDIT :

```
class B
{
   public:
  sem_t m_job_count; //added by RajaGopal
    B();
  void Init();
  void Init(char * s,int );

  void RegisterWorker(worker *aWorker);
  unsigned long getIndex(); 
  void setIndex(unsigned long index);

    char Msg[200];

    static void* ThreadProc(void *p);  

  ~B(); 
};
```

Comment: dbasic.... compiler saying that "`isUp' was not declared in this scope"

Comment: Where is the definition of class B?

Comment: Your example compiles just fine (g++-4.8.2) (With B defined as `class B {};`)

Comment: dbasic... I can not provide full code. but it is a thread application. But I have all the definition and it is local to class A so not need to definition of `Class B`

Comment: Show us the definition of `B` as well.

Comment: @user2845185 - Cannot see any problem - http://codepad.org/Ghjri4PZ

Comment: downvoting is very simple...this is I am facing and I told that this is strange. Please do max downvote. becoz when people dont know answer they downvote and said it can not happen.

Comment: Why have you declared constructors/destructors for B in the class workerthread?

Comment: What is your build environment? Either you are using some prehistoric system, or your compiler has a bug. The code is fine.

Comment: @user2845185: Definition of class B must be visible to class A in its header file. Where the header file of class B is included?

Comment: @all... this problem is coming if i introduced one new variable `isUp` in my class. class have 26 variables. If i simpley exclude this particular variable my project is working fine..

Comment: @user2845185 - Why not write some code that reproduces the problem instead of use trying to second guess what you are doing wrong?

Comment: EdHeal... Indirectly I need to provide my project... Sorry but I can not... I shall follow some other approach.

Answer (score 2):

Where is the definition of `class B`. Since you are inheriting class B, compiler needs to know the definition of class B. Include its header file or its definition too.

Class definition of B should be visible to A.

Otherwise, I have compiled this code [here](http://codepad.org/hqROXLRl) and did not faced any problem.

Comment: Sorry for this... But I declared that also. just not include it here.

Comment: See the edit and let me know if it can help you.

Comment: He *did* declared the default constructor for `A`.

Comment: I did everything u said.. If I remove that particular variable it is working fine. If I include it it is giving problem in my project.

Comment: @Jefffrey: At the time of writing answer, it was not there. Now, I have edited it.